# Can I unmount other drives when using a LiveCD installer to avoid a Windows 11 bootloader overwrite?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, gparted, 22.10

- My primary SSD contains Windows 11 using in UEFI mode using GPT
- *I'm thinking about installing Ubuntu Desktop 22.10 to a secondary SSD but wish to avoid overwriting the Windows bootloader.*

Can I do the following?

1. boot into the Ubuntu LiveCD installer
2. unmount all SSDs that I don't want Ubuntu installed on (using GParted)
3. install the OS and bootloader to just the one SSD?

In the past (2 years ago) I've accidentally overwrote it and it caused more of a headache than it was worth.

Comment: If you want dual boot the Ubuntu installer needs to see that there is another OS installed. You only need to pay attention when installing not to over write Windows. Hundreds maybe thousands do it every day.

Comment: If you unplug the Windows drive, you can not overwrite it. Once Ubuntu is installed, plug it back in then run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu Terminal, to add Windows to Ubuntu's bootloader. Make sure that you install Ubuntu as UEFI, (the same as Windows).